# Find global minimun with GD in PyTorch

Tags: python, regression, pytorch, gradient-descent, non-linear-regression

I have trained a NN with a vector input and scalar output (regression).
Now I want to find the global minimun of the NN using GD with pytorch.

I’m new to programming in general, python specifically, and pytorch even more specifically.

I believe what I’m trying to do must have been done a thousand times before, if not ten thousand times. I’ll be super happy and grateful if anyone could point me to some code somewhere (maybe in github) where there’s an example of what I’m trying to do that I could adjust to my needs.

Comment: meaning: 
I want to know what inputs will give the minimum (maximum) output

Comment: It is important to note that gradient based optimization is only guaranteed to find local minima. Only for special cases of your neural network and loss (if the loss function is convex) will GD produce the global minimum. It might be helpful to study how derivatives work in more detail, but the gradient is a local attribute giving the steepest slope at a single point. For a really brief introduction read [this](http://cs231n.github.io/optimization-1/)

Answer (score 0):

You do what you've done to train your network but instead of updating the weights, you update the input:

```
input = torch.zeros([1,3,32,32], requires_grad=True) # Whatever the expected input size of your network is
output = model(input)
target = 0.0 # What kind of target should your network reach?
loss = ((target - output) ** 2) # Replace this with the loss you are using
grad = torch.autograd.grad(loss, input)
```

You can apply the gradient (maybe multiplied with a learning rate) to the input and repeat this step many times. I've updated this from https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/gradient-of-loss-of-neural-network-with-respect-to-input/9482

You should pay attention to the fact that it's likely your network may produce a pretty noisy "inputs", so you should think about what your initial input should be. Google has done something similar before, see for example https://www.networkworld.com/article/2974718/software/deep-dream-artificial-intelligence-meets-hallucinations.html

Comment: great! thanks. this works perfectly. my code now looks like this:
for t in range(30):
    input = 100 * softmax(input), 
    output = net(input), 
    loss = -output, 
    loss_list.append(loss), 
    grad = torch.autograd.grad(loss, input), 
    grad = torch.tensor(grad[0]), 
    input -= learning_rate * grad. 

however, after a few updates the input becomes a one-hot-vector, which after applying softmax becomes 'Nan'. even if I use a highly-logical initial value (from the data used to train the NN)

any thoughts?

Comment: Your loss is just the negated output of the network, in regression, there should be something like a target value. And could you explain a bit about why you apply the transformation `input=100*softmax(input)`?

Comment: you are correct. :)  anyway, Everything works now. so, thanks to everyone very much for your help. Have a great autumn.